# Почему мы пишем  ча-ща, чу-щу?

Tags: орфография

Уважаемые филологи! Возможно, это не слишком оригинальный вопрос, но мне не удалось найти в Сети четкого, краткого  и понятного для всех  ответа. Понятно, что написание  жи-ши является традиционным и соответствует тому периоду, когда "ж" и "ш" были мягкими, но ведь  "ч" и "щ" были  мягкими всегда. Возможно, написание ча-ща, чу-щу связано с историей употребления букв "ю" и "я". Очень надеюсь получить ответ на вашем интересном форуме.Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Традиция написания слов с Я и Ю, возможно, связана с условиями употребления этих лигатур:  после гортанных к, г, х, шипящих ш, ч, ж, щ, а также в позиции после ц они  не применяются.

Ю после согласных вообще ставится не слишком свободно :

После м, в, б, ф, п практически всегда требует отделения при помощи мягкого знака (пью, вью, бью) или буквы л (коплю, люблю, графлю, ловлю, кормлю), но изредка могут и исключения встречаться (к голубю).

После с, з, т, д, имеет также ряд исторически обусловленных ограничений, позволяющих проставлять ю после данных согласных в ряде окончаний существительных (гвоздю, карасю, гостю, князю), но только не в глаголах (поскольку формы сляпсю, слямзю, постю, бдю - просторечные, а в языке литературном должно наблюдаться изменение согласных, напр. как в скольжу, снабжу, вакшу, пощусь).

Сейчас буква ю в церковнославянской орфографии встречается только после согласных л, н, р и (изредка) после т, д, с, з, но некогда в старо-московском (а теперь старообрядческом) изводе церк.-сл. языка активно применялась после мягких шипящих: чюти (чуять), чюдо и т.д.

«Я» в церковнославянском языке:

Правилами русского извода церковнославянского языка предписывается использование начертания (IA) в самом начале слов, а именно Я (выглядящего в шрифтах полуустава как Ѧ) на конце и в середине, исключая 2 момента:

• через Ѧ пишут личное местоимение я (также озн. 3 лицо винит. пад. мн. и двойств. числа «их»), но образующееся от него яже - относительное местоимение - (озн. которая, которых, которые) пишут через (IA));

• от смысла зависит отличие в написании слова языкъ и ряда
производных от него: через Ѧ пишут средство общения и орган речи, а через (IA) — народ (напр., «нашествие галлов и с ними двунадесяти язык»).

Букву Я (Ѧ) в в церковнославянском языке, в отличие от русского, порой пишут после шипящих (но, в этом случае читается как А). В данной позиции она используется, в основном, в таких случаях:

• в окончаниях существительных, местоимений, прилагательных и причастий указывает на множественное число: дщи наша (наша дочь) — дщєри нашя (наши дочери);

• в суффиксах действительных кратких причастий в настоящем времени (им. пад. сред. и муж. род. в ед. ч.) порой может применяться с формами аориста для снятия омонимии: слышя (слышащий, слыша) — слыша (они слыли — аорист от слыти; он/ты слышал, форма аориста от слышати), но зачастую его пишут и без особой надобности, напр., в полной форме слышяй (слышащий, слыша), не омонимичной ни с чем.

До XVII в. (порой и позднее) на Руси использовали и иные системы орфографии: так, (IA) могли писать после гласных и в началах слов, а после согласных — Я (Ѧ).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Мне особенно интересным показалось замечание об ограниченном применении букв я и ю после различных согласных, а не только после шипящих. Из этого следует, что исторически орфограмма ча-ща, чу-щу никак не связана с обозначением мягкости согласных ч и щ.

Answer (score 2):

Точный ответ могли бы дать те, кто когда-то начал так записывать звучание слогов, соединяя записи согласных и гласных звуков. Могу только сделать поверхностное предположение: в "мягких" согласных уже содержится эвуковой элемент, который заложен в звучание гласных я/ю в составе слогов с твёрдыми согласными. Иными словами, ня = ньа, ча = тшьа, а чя = тшььа - в последней записи дважды содержится элемент "мягкости", и это излишне подчёркивать в записи. При этом для мягких согласных нет слогов, в которых их звучание менялось бы на "твёрдое" (как в слоге "на"), т.е. не требуется второго варианта записи. Поэтому при выборе способа записи логично было остановиться на таком, который лишь однократно передаёт звуковое смягчение.

Заменить по аналогии "ё" на "о" повсеместно было бы нельзя уже потому, что в безударных слогах однокоренных слов может происходить трасформация в "е". "Э" с данными согласными используется только в написании иностранных названий. Например, при транскрипции с китайского по системе Палладия (используется с конца прошлого века) для передачи китайского твёрдого "ч" (примерно "тш") соотв. слоги записываются с буквой "э" (напр. Чэнь), и в составе русских вариантов собственных имён такая запись сохраняется.

С буквой "ы" тоже нельзя обойтись по аналогии с "а" и "у", поскольку гласные звуки, передаваемые буквами "ы" и "и" различаются независимо от того, c каким согласным (мягким или твёрдым) образован слог.

Это лишь то, что можно предположить на первый взгляд, сопоставив современное звучание слогов с современным же написанием; возможно, исторически было иначе и существуют более серьёзные объяснения.

Comment: Спасибо, вы приводите очень интересные рассуждения, но это именно современный взгляд на проблему в виде реконструкции, если считать, что звуки русского языка и буквы алфавита никак не изменились с того периода, когда создавалась древнерусская письменность. Но это не так. К примеру, слова «князь, пять» писались как кън(*)зь, 
п(*)ть, где буква * называлась «юс малый» и  обозначала носовой звук э, который к периоду создания письменности уже исчез из языка.

Comment: Вот на фоне такой исторической фонетики хотелось бы воссоздать историю написаний ча-ща, чу-щу и кратко изложить ее в виде, понятном современному пользователю.  Такие сведения представляются мне интересными и важными, их, к примеру, желательно применять при изучении орфографии в школе.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда твёрдые – [Ц]  [Ж]  [Ш]. Всегда мягкие – [Ч`]   [Щ`]   [Й`].

http://naurokax.ru/nuzhno-znat.htm

Такая уж классификация.

чаща связана со словом часто, часть.
чу со словом чую, чуть. щу - с ищу. Вам именно такая связь нужна?

Comment: Мне интересно, встречались ли вообще в русской письменности написания "чю-щю" и "чя-щя" (например, чюдо)и почему они не закрепились в языке.

Comment: А как вы произнесете   Я или Ю после мягкой  согласной?  у меня не получается, не вставив мягкий знак, чья, чью, шью, или чаю обещаю. Во всех русских словах именно так.  В заимствованиях это можно в написании щюцкор-schyutskor  финск, но произношение все равно через у, да и исходное немецкое чере у.

Comment: Я думаю, что произношение шипящих не зависит от последующей гласной, то есть после всегда твердых Ж, Ш, Ц и всегда мягких Ч, Щ  можно писать любую парную гласную. А какую именно - мы устанавливаем правилами (ча-ща, чу-щу, жи-ши, о/ё после шипящих, ы/и после ц). Это такое волевое решение, которое можно в любой момент изменить.